# d3 functions not working in node.js when rendering charts from the server side

Tags: node.js, d3.js

libraries & modules + their versions.

```
d3: ^7.0.0
dotenv: ^10.0.0
express: ^4.17.1
jsdom: ^16.6.0
```

I am trying to render charts on the server-side and send it through to the client side.

The issue that I a running into is that d3.[whatever function is here] gives me the error shown below.

However, if I console.log(d3) after importing the module I get the entire promise

```
const d3 = import("d3-selection");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const document = new JSDOM().window.document;

function getBarChart(){

    /* some code here runs perfectly */

    d3.select(document.body) // ERROR THROWN HERE.
        .append("div")
        .attr("id", params.parentID)
        .call(chart.render.bind(chart)); // rest of code is similar to this.

    /* some code here runs perfectly */

}
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: d3.select is not a function
    at getBarChart (D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\server\src\barchart\barchartgenerator.js:34:8)
    at D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\routes\api\svg.js:10:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
```

However this is what I get when I console.log(d3)

```
Promise {
  [Module: null prototype] {
    create: [Function: default],
    creator: [Function: default],
    local: [Function: local],
    matcher: [Function: default],
    namespace: [Function: default],
    namespaces: {
      svg: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
      xhtml: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      xlink: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
      xml: 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace',
      xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/'
    },
    pointer: [Function: default],
    pointers: [Function: default],
    select: [Function: default],
    selectAll: [Function: default],
    selection: [Function: selection],
    selector: [Function: default],
    selectorAll: [Function: default],
    style: [Function: styleValue],
    window: [Function: default]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? From what I know it'll return such an error when d3 is null. But it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You're using dynamic imports, which is likely not needed here. Just use the "normal" ones:

```
import d3 from "d3-selection";
import jsdom  from "jsdom";
```

[Dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) return a promise that resolves to the modules content. This can be used, when you need to load certain modules only under some conditions.

In your case, you want to import those two dependencies all the time, so you get just use the [static import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) as shown above.

---

<s>Apparently the whole project uses CommonJS, so you would need to use [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) instead of `import` (no matter whether you're using the static or dynamic version).</s>

edit: `d3` seems to use ESM by now, so a CommonJS approach should not be used anymore.

Comment: I get another error when I change it from
```const d3 = import("d3")```
to 
```import d3 from "d3-selection";```

Here it is:
```import d3 from "d3-selection";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module```

Comment: Is your nodejs project set to ESM (using modules) or CommonJS (the legacy standard within node)? In case of the latter, use `const d3 = require('d3')`

Comment: How do i check if its set to ESM? in package.json I cant find anything

Comment: If there is no [`"type": "module"`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_type) in your `packagae,json`, you are using CommonJS almost certainly.

Comment: ```Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\Github repositories\data-viz-project\node_modules\d3\src\index.js  
require() of ES modules is not supported.```

Is what i get when i use ```require()```

Comment: ok. apparently `d3` is now published as an ESmodule itself. I'd make your project use ESM as well. For that just add the `"type": "module"` line to your `package.json` and use `import` (static) in your scripts.

Comment: I found the problem! All that time it was returning a promise and I was using d3 methods on the promise. Turns out what I have to do is d3.then(d3 => d3).then(/* MY CODE HERE */). But is there a way to break the Promise and have d3 as the d3 object itself?

Comment: Did you read the links I provided for the difference between dynamic and static `import`? Your answer pretty much boils down to understanding the difference.